# What bitcoin exchanges are based in the USA?

Tags: exchanges, usa

What are the names and Web site addresses of popular bitcoin exchanges based in the USA?  These exchanges should support account funding via ACH transfers from US bank accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have missed a few, but here are the main ones based in the USA:

- [Coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/) (not really an exchange)
- [GDAX](https://www.gdax.com/) (part of Coinbase)
- [Poloniex](https://poloniex.com/)
- [Gemini](https://gemini.com/)

Mind you that many other exchanges based out of other countries are just as likely to accept funding via ACH.

Comment: Which bitcoin exchanges in foreign countries accept payment via ACH?

Comment: I'd argue that Coinbase is an exchange with Coinbase being the only  counterparty.

Comment: It seems https://cex.io/ and https://www.gocelery.com/  (not an exchange) do. But your original question was about exchanges based in the US. I do not believe these are, but it appears they do accept ACH wires for funding.

Comment: I guess these exchanges must have bank accounts in the USA.